# Multiple users using same API at same time, for each request from the users should increment the value by 1 and reset after reaching max value to 99

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have a requirement,

1. For each request, the value (initial value = 1) of Id should increment by 1 until it reaches the max count say 99. Once reaches 99 it should reset to 1 in dataweave.
2. When multiple users uses the above API at same time, the value should increment by 1 for each request and reset the value to 1 after reaching 99.

Comment: Why do you want to reset in dataweave? For this, you would add the increment and reset logic in a variable and use the variable in dataweave.

Comment: Mulesoft rate limiting policy has some logic that can help on this challenge. But if you need to synchronize multiple replicas its very challenging and costly to keep a sequence. There are also specific scenarios like the ones tackled by Partner Manager, where the tool handles the sequence

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the Object Store, if you are willing to sacrifice performance.

@aled's answer is accurate about the lack of ACID semantics, and a third party database would provide a performant transactional solution.

The basic design is to retrieve a counter from a value in the Object Store, increment it, and store the result like so:

```
    <os:retrieve doc:name="counter" key="counter" objectStore="counterObjectStore" target="counter" targetValue="#[payload as Number]">
        <os:default-value ><![CDATA[#[0]]]></os:default-value>
    </os:retrieve>
    <set-variable value="#[vars.counter + 1 mod 100]" doc:name="increment counter" variableName="counter"/>
    <os:store doc:name="counter" key="counter" objectStore="counterObjectStore">
        <os:value ><![CDATA[#[vars.counter]]]></os:value>
    </os:store>
```

Because the object store does not provide any locking semantics, the concurrency risk is that two different requests read the same value, and as a result they both store the same result.  To remedy that, you can encapsulate this logic in a private flow with `maxConcurrency="1"` to ensure that only one mule event is executing this logic at a time.

Further, you will have to deploy the application to a single node only. I recommend choosing a non-persistent object store to help improve the performance of this counter logic.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Mule Runtime (the engine) and DataWeave (the language) persist information internally. You need some persistence layer outside the Mule application to persist information between requests, like a database or a file. Only some kind of database will provide the kind of transactional operation to avoid concurrency issues with multiple users. Also the Object Store connector is not appropriated for this usage as you can read in the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store-connector/latest/#object-store-limitations).